How to Observe and reload bean if connection status changes
I have a spring boot application with redis cache support
During runtime is there a way to detect if redis server is down/up ?
And based on that reload the Bean that is connecting app with redis to reload
E.g if connection is OK use redisCacheManagerOnline bean when redis is online and redisCacheManagerOffline bean when redis is offline
Sample code
`@Bean
fun redisCacheManagerOnline(
    jedisConnectionFactory: JedisConnectionFactory,
    redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, Any>
): CacheManager {
    val redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
        .disableCachingNullValues()
        .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(1))
        .serializeValuesWith(
            RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(redisTemplate.valueSerializer)
        )
    return RedisCacheManager
        .RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory)
        .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration)
        .build()
}

@Bean
fun redisCacheManagerOffline(): CacheManager {
    return NoOpCacheManager()
}`

Is there a way to do this when app is running?
I tried redisCacheManagerOnline  with try catch and return NoOpCacheManager() if there is any error but it does not work when app is running and I shutdown the redis server
